# Can a bottom border be moved horizontal across?

Tags: html, css

If I have a bottom border on a `div` element. Is there a way, the border can just be slid across without moving the whole div?

For instance:
http://jsfiddle.net/jLCSX/

```
<div class="contactusside">
     <h2>Contact Details</h2>

    <p><b>Phone:</b> 
        <br>1111111111</p>
    <p><b>Fax:</b> 
        <br>111111111</p>
    <p><b>Email:</b> sales@123.com</p>
    <p><b>Address:</b> 
        <br>123laneway ave
        <br>(PO Box xxx)
        <br>balh ablah
        <br>country</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p></p>
    <br>
</div>
```

```
.contactusside {
    width: 210px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}
.contactusside h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Can I move this bottom border to the right so it lines up with the top one?

Comment: In your fiddle both borders are to the right

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jLCSX/1/?

Comment: What is the difference between the fiddle from the answer that you have marked correct http://jsfiddle.net/y45D3/ and your fiddle in your question http://jsfiddle.net/jLCSX/ ??

Comment: In my fiddle, the bottom border is slightly pushed to the left so that it meets with the left border at the corner, whereas where I wanted it and what the other fiddle shows that the border lines up (on vertical edges) to the border underneath the heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the fiddle:

[fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/y45D3/)

```
Put: <div class="bottom-border"></div>
```

and the css:

```
.bottom-border { border-bottom: 1px solid #777; }
```

also remove the bottom border you have set.

```
.contactusside {
width: 210px;
float: right;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 15px;
border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottom border is part of the `div`.

If you mean that you want the bottom border to line up with the `h2`'s bottom border, I'd recommend putting the contents of that `div` within its own `div`, and give that a top and bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the border to only be part way, but you could use either another div or an `<hr>` element to simulate that effect. eg:

```
<div>
//content

    <div style="width:50%;position:absolute;right:0;border-bottom:1px solid black"></div>
</div>
```